# "Finish Sharing" buttons greyed out for Copy all data when sharing as a web layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal

I have a federated ArcGIS Portal 10.9.1 and I use ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 for publishing. I'm trying to publish a layer as a Tile service (Copy all data) to Portal using the 'Share As Web Layer' tool in Pro, but the 'Finish Sharing' buttons are greyed out. I've populated everything necessary, and tried checking and unchecking various boxes as well as different tiling schemes to no avail. The same issue occurs for any layer as well.

[image]

**My Question**

Why are these buttons greyed out and how can I get them to work? I can publish web services fine when any of the 'Reference registered data' options are checked.

Comment: Check with your GIS Administrator. There may not be a hosting server configured with your ArcGIS Enterprise environment.

Comment: You were right, the hosting server wasn't connected enabled in the ArcGIS Portal/Enterprise settings. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent! Moving my comment to answer. Can you mark it as accepted if you feel it helped answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with your GIS Administrator. There may not be a hosting server configured with your ArcGIS Enterprise environment.